# How to hide a zero value bar when faceting in ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with many columns and I want to plot the frequency distribution of "Nivel Educativo" (factor, 9 levels), according to "Tipo de vivienda" (factor, 4 levels: "Casa", "Departamento", "Pieza de hotel", "Pieza de inq") and faceting it by "dominio" (factor, 2 levels: "villa" and "no villa").

```
ggplot(hogares, aes(x=Tipo_vivienda, fill=niv_educ, weight=fexp))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  labs(x = "Tipo de vivienda",  title = "Niv educ de le jefe de hogar (binario)")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 30))+
  facet_grid(cols = vars(dominio))
```

But there is no observation that simultaneously is a "Pieza de hotel" and placed at a "villa".  Therefore, when faceting, I will always have an empty bar. It is not an NA, there is simply no observation with this combination of values.

[image: 1]

I could make a new column combining "Tipo de vivienda" and "dominio" but I would lose comparability. I just want one facet to have all four values and the other only three.

I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: It's a little difficult to answer without some example data, but I think adding `scales = "free_x"` to your `facet_grid()` will help.

Comment: that works! thank you! I knew it was something simple but couldn't find it.